# template class - member function specialization

Tags: c++

Here is an example code:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
   A(T t): x(t){}
   T getX();
private:
   T x;
};

template<class T>
T A<T>::getX()
{
   return x;
}

// member function specialization
template<> // works with and without template<> 
long A<long>::getX()
{
   return 1000L;
}
```

The above code works with and without **template<>** before a member function specialization. Why ?
What difference does it make in such case ?

**Edit1:**
I use that template this way (VS 2012 compiler):

```
A<int> a1(1);
cout<<a1.getX()<<endl;
A<long> a2(1);
cout<<a2.getX()<<endl;
```

Comment: What compiler version are you using?

Comment: templates won't be generated without the specific calls, can you please paste the code you are using to call this template functions?

Comment: **IFF** there's an explicit specialization of `A<long>` before that declaration, you must not use the `template<>`. Otherwise, you must use it. Nice, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Not compliantly, it doesn't.**

FWIW, [GCC 4.8 rejects your code without the `template <>`.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a539f8064c4a18e8)

Your compiler is either buggy or has an extension to support this; I can confirm that MSVS 2012 accepts the code. I'm told that MSVS 2013 November CTP also eats it up without complaint. To be fair, Visual Studio was always fairly lenient about template specifications.

> `[C++11: 14.7/3]:` **An explicit specialization may be declared for** a function template, a class template, **a member of a class template** or a member template. **An explicit specialization declaration is introduced by `template<>`.** *[..]*

The only exception to this rule is:

> `[C++11: 14.7.3/5]:` *[..]* Members of an explicitly specialized class template are
>   defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the `template<>` syntax. *[..]*

… but that does not apply here.

Comment: *"Your compiler is either buggy or has an extension to support this"* Why "or"? It is buggy if it doesn't emit at least a warning, and it has an extension as the program isn't rejected.

Comment: @DyP: It could be buggy and not an extension.

Comment: @DyP: I hate when that happens